# why miss some code after compress with uglify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a js and use uglify to compress

```
 ;(function() {

    function gE(el) {
        return document.getElementById(le);
    }



    function rd(n,m) {
        var c = m - n + 1;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * c + n);
    }

    var el = {
        info: gE('info'),
        scrollvivew: gE('scrollview'),
        box: gE('box')
    };

    var setting = {
        scWidth: 5500,
        scHeight: 5500,
        bxWidth: 100,
        bxHeight: 100
    };


})();
```

but after compress, I got the min version js is

```
!function(){  
   function a(a){return document.getElementById(le)}  
  ({info:a("info"),scrollvivew:a("scrollview"),box:a("box")})}();
```

some code gone, so what's the problem?

here is my `Gruntfile.js` config about uglify

```
uglify: {
            compress: {
                options: {
                    banner: '',
                    compress: !0
                },
                files: {
                    "build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js": [ "src/**/*.js" ]
                }
            }

        }
```

and I have tried with `beautify` option,  also miss some code..

Comment: Did it remove unused code?

Comment: @jfriend00 omg,it seems you are right!

Comment: `rd()` is unused, `setting` is unused - so why keep it?

Comment: but sometimes I need to use it to format pretty...and the code not finish yet @Andreas